# Last UICollectionViewCell appearing different to the others

Tags: swift

I'm creating a `UICollectionView` on my main menu and all the cells look fine bar the last one, where the image is not centered relative to the cell- it appears to be anchored to the top left corner of the cell (not sure about that though).

***here is the image that contains the problem.***

[image: https://pasteboard.co/InC8qlK.png]

I didn't really know where to start with this, as all the cells use the same code and constraints.
I checked that it wasn't an image issue by repeating a previously used image (see above screenshot)

My only idea is that the final cell is in a row on its own whereas the other rows have two cells per row.

```swift
extension MainMenuViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainMenuOptions.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MainMenuCollectionViewCell
        let imageView = cell.mainMenuImage!
        let label = cell.mainMenuLabel!

        imageView.image = mainMenuImages[indexPath.item]
        imageView.frame.size.height = cell.frame.size.width - 5
        imageView.frame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width - 10

        cell.mainMenuLabel.text = mainMenuOptions[indexPath.item]
        let labelText = cell.mainMenuLabel!
        label.frame.size.height = Utils.heightForView(text: labelText.text!, font: labelText.font!, width: cell.frame.width)
        label.frame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width
        label.center.x = cell.frame.size.width / 2
        label.center.y = cell.mainMenuImage.frame.size.height + (cell.frame.size.height - cell.mainMenuImage.frame.size.height) / 2

        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(0.5)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(10)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MainMenuCollectionViewCell
        let padding: CGFloat = 40
        let cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.width - padding) / 2
        let labelText = mainMenuOptions[indexPath.item]
        let cellHeight = cellWidth + Utils.heightForView(text: labelText, font: cell.mainMenuLabel.font!, width: cell.frame.width) + 70

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }

}
```

`Utils.heightForView()` is just a function that calculates the size required for a label to fit all the text. If you need to see it I'll happily add it.

Thanks very much in advance! I hope this is the right amount of code needed but if not let me know and I'll add more.

EDIT: Cell class

```swift
class MainMenuCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainMenuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainMenuImage: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Try adding one more cell to the data source. See what happens.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/InCf0f3.png both the original and the extra cell have the same issue

Comment: I think the problem is you haven't reset everything when you reuse the cell. Can you show your cell class?

Comment: Added in an above edit :)

Answer (score 0):

When you dequeue a cell in `cellForItem` it doesn't necessarily have its final size at that point, yet you're depending on that being correct for your code to work.

You should be using autolayout constraints or a stack view inside the cell to give you the correct layout without needing to do any work at dequeue time.

You seem to be trying to give variable heights for your cells as well, which is going to look pretty messy in a flow layout, although it doesn't seem to be making any difference to the cells in the screenshot which I'd expect to have different heights given their titles. Dequeuing a cell in `sizeForItem` could have some unexpected side effects too, since that's going to mess with the reuse pool.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you mean. I've tried using auto layout constraints before but then my images get really wacky. I'll go back to using auto layout and see where that gets me.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I'd start with a vertical stack view, which is pinned to the edges of the cell, then put the image view and label inside that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I've done that and got rid of all the other useless code. If I want to dynamically resize the cell size based off the screen size (that's what I was really going for originally), can I do that via auto layout constraints or should I be doing that programatically?

Comment: You'd need to do that in your size delegate method, or set `itemSize` on the layout when your view changes size